# Activities null pointer exception - How to debug

Tags: android, android-activity, nullpointerexception, reference

I have a "SignUpActivity" where user can sign in to my application, in some rare cases (I got only a few from Fabric, Crashlytics) that this particular activity is finishing before a dialog is shown. To clarify this, check the code below:

```
  private void register() {
    final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    dialog.setTitle("Registering");
    dialog.setMessage("Please wait..");
    if (dialogReady(dialog)) {
        dialog.show();
    }
    final AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Error Occured")
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                }
            }).create();


    new ApiService(this).signUp(signUpModel).enqueue(new Callback<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Void> call, Response<Void> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                //code
                finish();
            } else {
                if (dialogReady(dialog) && dialogReady(alert)) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    alert.setMessage(response.message());
                    alert.setMessage("Email already exists");
                    alert.show();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Void> call, Throwable t) {
            if (dialogReady(dialog) && dialogReady(alert)) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                alert.setMessage("Check your internet connection");
                alert.show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

How I managed to recreate the problem is by setting "Don't keep activities" in the Developer options. I managed to fix this by using the dialogReady method I created:

```
 private boolean dialogReady(Dialog dialog) {
    return (dialog != null && !this.isFinishing());
}
```

However, I'm really curious to know why my activity is finished whnen clearly from the code there's no way (or there is) for it to finish before a dialog is shown or dismissed. I checked Crashlytics and all the devices have 30+% of RAM available and the activity itself is pretty simple and doesn't use much Memory anyway.

This also popped when referencing an Activity. I have an activity, let's call it A. A opens an activity B, which uses a static variable from A, call it A.listener. When assigning it to a new instance of that listener in the activity B, it throws a null pointer exception on A. I couldn't recreate that with "Don't keep activities" and this only happens on a few devices.

How can I perhaps think of a way to recreate the problem. A good process I could follow to debugging this rare problem.

Thank you.

EDIT: The call I'm doing (new ApiService....) is an async *request* *(using retrofit)

Comment: Have you thought of using AsyncTask? I think it would be recommended do to such actions in Background (checking with Backend) and in main Thread you would display ProgressDialog.

Comment: @AndroidNFC I'm using retrofit's async *request* *, the call I'm doing new ApiService.. is Async.

Comment: But I cannot see in your code where you dismiss(); your dialog or maybe I am blind? So if I think correctly, the process is: You call register(); first, so the Dialog should show now. And then it should start the background thread to check if SignUp is correct and dismiss the Dialog accordingly if it's succesfull (this part I do not see), you only dismiss if it's Error occured. So your ProgressDialog is not showing AT ALL, correct?

Comment: Yes it's showing, everything is working as it should be by using the method in my question (dialogReady), check before the Call, there's a if(dialogready) dialog.show() and there is both dimisss in both failures (and even on successful too, i removed that bcz it was a biig block of code and it was the last line, so there is a dismiss there too. What I want is a way to debug such problems. (Null pointer exceptions on activities). If you check my 2nd example, that's the one I'm failing to debug and recreate

Comment: You can probably do that as user? Hold home button and then clear memory? Also some Androids do kill activities just so, when they think they were running long enough (especially while in background). And to get to the background you may for example just receive a call, or something... hard to say, the Android OS does not guarantee your activity to stay in memory for long, the debug option "Don't keep activities" simulates the worst-case-scenario, which really happens, on some devices often enough to be not ignored. (one more I recall ... `onConfigurationChanged` things may do havoc too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@PampaZiya, I think you have to use the [Weak Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html) Activity

Where context of activity store in Weak Reference which will use in popup initialization so after activity finish the reference of activity still live, then by the use of this reference there no crash occur.

you can use weak reference of activity as

```
WeakReference<Activity> weakReferenceActivity;
```

initialize in onCreate of activity as

```
weakReferenceActivity = new WeakReference<Activity>(activity);
```

Now, Use this reference to initialize the progressbar or progressdialog also you can use even in AlertDialog also as.

```
final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(weakReferenceActivity );

final AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(weakReferenceActivity );
```

Now whenever you activity finish the dialog use the following reference to dismiss so the crash is not come in picture.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is this the recommended way of doing things? Or would you call it a hack? I would like to know the most optimal way of referencing. 

Also does this work with static variables? In my 2nd example, I want the reference of the static variable "listener" in activity A.

Comment: @PampaZiya, I dont know about your question of "would you call it a hack?". But I am sure that the reference will work with static variables.

Comment: It seems to be working just fine. Thank you ! Accepted answer.

Comment: @PampaZiya, Welcome!

Answer (score 0):

When you want to show the dialog first check activity != null and !activity.isfinishing() like:

```
if(!isFinishing())
{
    //show alert
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I have included a snapshot of a method I'm using to do that which contains your solution, which is optimal. However, my problem is I want a method to debug such problems and recreate them for further testing.

Comment: Sorry but ,I am not getting you